# PG: Fetching "day" records using start_date and end_date columns

Tags: postgresql

Each record has a "date range", represented by `start_date` and `end_date` columns.  When the start_date and end_date are the same date value, that record spans one day.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| foo_count | start_date |  end_date  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|        25 | 2014-02-11 | 2014-02-17 | <- spans one week
|        30 | 2014-02-20 | 2014-02-20 | <- spans one day
|        15 | 2014-02-21 | 2014-02-21 | <- spans one day
|        45 | 2014-02-22 | 2014-02-22 | <- spans one day
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Is there a way to fetch *only* records that represent a *single day* (i.e. the start_date and end_date match)?

Comment: I have a feeling you have not explained the problem properly because the answer is too simple ... WHERE start_date = end_date ?

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure I can explain it any better, but here goes... The "events" table has events that span various date ranges. Some events may last a week (see first row in my example), some events may last only a single day (see last three rows in example).  I'd like to fetch only events that span a single day.

Comment: In that case the WHERE clause in my earlier comment should work

Comment: @harmic Thanks, man.  To make things a bit more difficult though, what if I were only interested in events that span a week? In which case, it wouldn't be as simple as just checking for matching start_date and end_date columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match records that span a single day:

```
SELECT * FROM footable WHERE start_date = end_date;
```

To match records that span a week:

```
SELECT * FROM footable WHERE  end_date - start_date = 6;
```

[This page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) in the manual shows date and time operators. Subtracting two dates gives the number of days between.

Btw I would normally arrange the boundaries of such a range so that only one end was inclusive, ie. Start <= date < end, so that subtracting end - start gives the actual number of days.